# Query only use join operation

Tags: sql, join

I have a database like the image below
[image: DB description]

The question is:
[image: Question]

My query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(book.bookdescID),book.title,book.subtitle,book.edition,book.place
FROM book
LEFT JOIN book_copy
ON book.bookdescID = book_copy.bookdescID
LEFT JOIN borrow_copy
ON book_copy.bookID = borrow_copy.bookID
WHERE borrow_copy.bookID IS NULL
```

The problem is that there are books which have a version of a copy that has already been borrowed, while another version of the copy hasn't been borrowed yet. My query still considers that the book has never been borrowed before and that result is false. Can anyone provide a solution for this?
[image: same book, different book copy, one copy already borrowed by people, the other have not be borrowed by anyone]

Comment: Just an idea: what if you try to use `INNER JOIN borrow_copy`? I think you should take only really borrowed books (joining *book_copy* and *borrow_copy*, maybe in a subquery if needed) and then use `LEFT JOIN` with *book* table

Comment: the problem is I am not allowed to use anything except the JOIN operations, otherwise, this one is very easy.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I recommend not using parentheses with `DISTINCT`. They make the query less readable, because they make it look like `DISTINCT` were a function applying to the column in parentheses only, while it is actually a keyword applying to the whole row.

Comment: thank your for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I don't like such tasks where you are asked to write a query in a way you should not write it.

Anyway, combine book_copy and borrow_copy in a subquery (aka derived table) and outer join this data set, so as to get a NULL only when a book has no match in there.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM book b
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM book_copy bkc
  JOIN borrow_copy brc ON brc.bookid = bkc.bookid
) bb ON bb.bookdescid = b.bookdescid
WHERE bb.bookdescid IS NULL;
```

Comment: the result is absolutely right thank you so much